# Can Redis AOF-Persistence set to 'always' have better performace then 'every sec'?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, redis

I am currently in the process of deciding on the database-portion of a new Web-Application.

the Application will be run on a windows Server and will be in .Net

As the Application should be very low on writes and high on reads, and i do not expect this application to have a complex relation-wise Domain,  I was looking for something faster then my default option, which is EF.

I am now on the point that i am currently deciding on 2 setups:

1. EF for persistence, Redis for (manual) cache
2. Full Redis persistence implementation

In my research i found that the AOF persistence in Redis seems decent, but that there is a trade-off on performance.

In the docs and other resources it is allways stated that the 'always' option is very, very slow and the 1sec option is a good compromise.

Now, in my understanding, the AOF write can only happen on a dataset change, hence a write. So am i right in concluding that in my situation the 'always' option is the beter / faster choice, because i will most likely only get a data-write every hour or so? or is the 1 sec, more meant as a limit (as in we will write for every comaand with a max of once a second)

I feel a bit silly asking this, but i could not find a straight answer for this and to me it does kind of determines my choice on this matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to perform 1 write per hour, then it doesn't matter if Redis does the `fsync` every write or every second.

In my case I would go with the "1 second" option, since it's true that if server goes down once you've changed data during the next second you're going to lose the whole change, since a server down is something that won't happen everyday and every hour, I would go with the so-called option because it will scale better if you decide to do more writes every hour...